# Design for Boost ASIO , Worker threads SQl queries for 'practical' web server

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, blocking

I am looking for solution to develop an efficient web server framework where:

1. One or few IO threads handle client HTTP connections and TCP IO.
2. Multiple threads do business processing (SQL queries, file IO,  etc.)

All blogs solution I have seen are solving 10000 connections with worker threads doing almost zero business logic (i.e just writing data using `async_write`).  Is the Boost.Asio's [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3) a solution for my problem?  If so, how many threads should I use per core?

I am also interested in knowing how [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3) compares to the 1 acceptor thread + thread pool model used by [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. According to [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) you should try to ask *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"*. "I am looking for suggestions" doesn't seem to fit that very will.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that , But pls look beyond that line , why do feel that my problem is non practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to use the comments, so I have to post a new answer to give any input.

O.P. is asking a specific question about http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/.
This is an example http server that starts a thread pool to handle the http requests.

O.P.'s original question might be restated: "given a server machine with a set of resources A and a workload that consumes B resources per request, how many threads should I allocate in the thread pool?"

There's a thread here: [Reasonable number of threads for thread pool running web service requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028707/resonable-number-of-threads-for-thread-pool-in-java) with a similar discussion (with respect to Java thread pools) but that discussion doesn't seem to come to any conclusive answer.

Here's an example of a short tutorial on capacity planning in the "old fashioned 1970's mainframe style" that I learned in school: http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/goalmode/primer.pdf.

In this case you might create a simple model like:

You have an average rate of requests arriving, X.  For each request you are consuming a certain average amount of cpu (in units of time) S_c, and an average amount of time spent waiting for disk requests to complete, S_d.  So each thread is taking an average time S_c + S_d before it is returned to the thread pool. (You would need to measure this.)  Thus on average you would expect that you would need at least N = X * (S_c+S_d) threads to avoid incoming threads queueing at an empty thread pool.  You might actually want to allocate some small multiple of N (e.g. 3N) threads to be able to deal with bursts of one kind or another.

But the number of threads in the pool isn't really the interesting limit.  The interesting limit is either the total amount of CPU or the total amount of disk bandwidth you have available.  Suppose each request requires 3 seconds of CPU processing, and that you have a system with 12 cores.  Thus, in any 3 second period you should expect to handle 12 simultaneous requests.  Thus an average arrival rate greater than 12/3 = 4 requests per second would saturate your CPU.  (Similar calculation for your disk bandwidth.)

So really what you are going to end up figuring out is: given my expected arrival rate of requests, X, and the amount of CPU and disk consumed by each request, *how much cpu and disk should I purchase?*

Comment: Thanks, @Wandering Logic Also my question was related to 

How best to use ASIO for HTTP applications where worker has to do long blocking like sql query , file io etc etc

Comment: If you are already creating multiple threads for each http request, then I see no added value to asio.  ASIO is a way of allowing a single thread to handle many requests without worrying about the *order* in which they arrive.  It would typically make your business logic considerably more complicated.  (Your sequential order of things to do in your business logic gets divided up into a bunch of continuations which are fed as the return handlers to the async i/o operations.)

Comment: for read request , Its nothing much , but later to write Data needs to be prepared and then queued.
My issue is after read , **preparation** of data. [How various asynch frameworks solve this problem efficiently & elegently is the question , any refrences would be helpful]
I don't care on which order its written.

Comment: boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html. But asio is horrible for business logic. Instead: for each http request create a thread (or put the request on a queue that will be serviced by a thread pool.)  Each thread will execute the business logic for a single request.  Each thread will perform *blocking* i/o operations, but it doesn't matter because all the other requests are being serviced asynchronously by other threads.  With threads you can use local variables that store data across blocking i/o calls.  With asio you need to manage all that state explicitly.

Comment: Thans , I will do it , 
After studying most of options , I have nearly come to conclusion <br/>
A] One thread for epoll <br/>
B] Pool for business logic <br/>
C] Queue between IO thread & pool <br/>
D] pipe between IO thread & pool to wake IO thread for write data <br/>
E] accept & client read & write  be done by IO thread<br/>
And I guess ngix & lighthttpd follow same ?

Answer (score 0):

After studying most of options , I have nearly come to conclusion 
A] One thread for epoll 
B] Pool for business logic 
C] Queue between IO thread & pool 
D] pipe between IO thread & pool to wake IO thread for write data 
E] accept & client read & write  be done by IO thread
And I guess ngix & lighthttpd follow same ?

Comment: I'm not sure what "epoll" is.  I would use one thread to listen and accept() for new connections, then use boost's [Message Queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue) to pass the newly accepted file descriptor to the thread pool and then go back to accept() the next .  Then let the thread in the thread pool do all the client logic _and write the data_ and then goes back to the message queue to await then next client.  Just use a mutex to protect the writes.  That will serialize them.